# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wl' in Makfile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

I run the command "**make test**" in this source code:

https://github.com/sanandrea/CSecretKey

but it give me this **error**:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wl'
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'lib_plain' failed
make: *** [lib_plain] Error 1
```

This is the line 18 in the makefile
    gcc -shared -Wl -o libhmacenc.so hmac_256_plain.o sha2.o -lc

This is the list of the files:

- Android.mk
- hmac_sha256.c
- hmac_sha256.h
- reverse_test.py
- sha2.c
- sha2.h
- test.c

This is the complete "makefile":

```
all: lib test
test: clean lib_plain
    gcc -o test test.c -lhmacenc -L.

production: clean lib
    gcc -o test test.c -lhmacenc -L.

hmac_256.o: hmac_sha256.c hmac_sha256.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c hmac_sha256.c -o hmac_256.o

hmac_256_plain.o: hmac_sha256.c hmac_sha256.h
    $(CC) -Wall -DSHOW_PASS -c hmac_sha256.c -o hmac_256_plain.o

lib: hmac_256.o sha2.o
    gcc -shared -Wl -o libhmacenc.so hmac_256.o sha2.o -lc

lib_plain: hmac_256_plain.o sha2.o
    gcc -shared -Wl -o libhmacenc.so hmac_256_plain.o sha2.o -lc

sha2.o: sha2.c sha2.h
    $(CC) -c sha2.c -o sha2.o

clean:
    - rm -rf *.o hmac *.so
```

Someone would knows how I can fix this error?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `-Wl` was suppose to be `-Wall` or they were trying to pass an option to the linker and forget which is what -Wl is for.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html

Comment: Yeah, that's just a broken makefile. And (I haven't looked at the code at all) but I would think **very carefully** about using "random" cryptographic code like that.

Comment: @EtanReisner   what do you mean in "very carefully"? Thanks for response

Comment: I mean I have no idea what the quality of that code is and crypto code is **very** hard to write safely and correctly. Even the professionals make mistakes. So, without knowing *significantly* more about the provenance of that code I would in no way shape or form recommend using it. Use an established crypto library instead.

Comment: @EtanReisner   thanks for your time! :) At the moment is the only what I have...

Comment: Then spend your time finding a better source. Seriously, it will serve you better in the end then having whatever you are working on compromised by bad crypto code.

Comment: @EtanReisner   Thanks! I'm on it. It's for a JNI in Android :) to encrypt the public key

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is another branch of the code that deals with Cygwin and has a different Makefile.

https://github.com/sanandrea/CSecretKey/tree/cygwin

Always try to use a GNU-Linux environment to compile programs in pure C. Avoid Cygwin because their behavior is different in the Makefile.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @missimer, there is option field not specified in your makefile for linker option '-Wl'.

Generally, for creating shared library, the following syntax is used with '-Wl':

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-export-dynamic
```

Hope this helps you.